# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I've run into another problem with a personal project of mine that has been causing griviences. Please excuse me if the solution is obvious, I'm quite new to python.

The issue is that when I run this program, I get an error that says

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'int'

I'm unsure how to fix this as the other queries about this issue are about codes I find difficult to understand and consequently cannot understand the solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
 def totalcalc(total1,total2):                   
    if total1 % 2 == 0:                         
        total1 = total1 + 10
    else:
        total1 = total1 - 5
    if total2 % 2 == 0:
        total2 = total2 + 10
    else:
        total2 = total2 - 5
    return total1,total2

total1 = 0
total2 = 0

total1 = int(input("num1: "))
total2 = int(input("num2: "))
total1 = totalcalc(total1,total2)
total2 = totalcalc(total1,total2)
print(total1)
print(total2)
```

Comment: `total1 = totalcalc(total1,total2)` returns a tuple.

Comment: Use `total1, total2 = totalcalc(total1,total2)` instead of two lines which makes `total1` a tuple

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try

```
def totalcalc(total1,total2):                   
    if total1 % 2 == 0:                         
        total1 = total1 + 10
    else:
        total1 = total1 - 5
    if total2 % 2 == 0:
        total2 = total2 + 10
    else:
        total2 = total2 - 5
    return total1,total2

total1 = 0
total2 = 0

total1 = int(input("num1: "))
total2 = int(input("num2: "))
FinalAnswer = totalcalc(total1,total2)

print("Total1:{}".format(FinalAnswer[0]))
print("Total1:{}".format(FinalAnswer[1]))
```

Aur Just Try Multilevel Variable assignment as Said By @Chris

```
total1, total2 = totalcalc(total1,total2)
print(total1)
print(total2)
```